# Topological threading in 3+1 dimensions

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

I am attempting to extrapolate a 3D case to 4D. I hope it's alright to use some physics terminology. 2+1 space = 2 spatial dimensions and 1 time dimension. World-line/sheet/volumes are simply the objects traced out as the spatial dimension progresses through time.

Suppose you have a 2+1 space with a stationary particle tracing out a world line. Now imagine that for a period of time you take a line segment constrained to the 2-space and form it into a circle around that particle. You then break the circle and remove the line segment. When one looks at the world volumes this will result in a 'threading' action where the the particle world-line is threaded through a hole in the line segment world-sheet.

[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNNx8.jpg)

Now my question is, when we upgrade to 4D. i.e. when we temporarily surround a stationary particle in 3D by forming a 2D surface into a sphere, and then break that sphere and remove the 2D surface, do we obtain the same kind of 'threading' action as we saw in the previous case.

Any advice as to what formalism could be used to examine such things would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain the 2nd paragraph more, possibly with a picture? What does forming a line into a circle around a point mean? What does breaking the circle and removing the line segment mean? How does this result in a threading?

Comment: ok, I added a picture, let me know if you can see it well enough. Sorry for the poor image quality

Answer (score 1):

In the picture you drew, the point traces out a vertical line and the line/circle in each slice traces out a surface. I can see two ways to read your picture which give slightly different surfaces.

The first way to read your picture is that the vertical line on the right of the point in the first picture remains there no matter how high we go and that the vertical line on the right of the point in the last picture is there no matter how low we go. In this case, the surface traced out is a non-compact surface with two boundary components.

The second way to read your picture is that the vertical lines in the first and last pictures disappear to a point and then to nothing at some height (both up and down). In this case, the surface we've traced out is just a cylinder.

In one higher dimension, basically the same thing happens. Each slice is now a $3$-dimensional picture. In the initial slice, we have a point together with a surface with boundary. However, here we have quite a bit more choice than in $2+1$-dimensional case, and that choice is a choice of surface. Our surface could be a $2$-dimensional sphere or a connected sum of $g$ different tori (called the genus $g$ surface). See [here](https://people.math.osu.edu/fiedorowicz.1/math655/classification.html) for more details. For simplicities sake, I'm not considering the non-orientable surfaces.

The "easiest" surface to consider would be the sphere, and here the story unfolds like the $2+1$-dimensional case. The sphere has a small "hole" in it where the boundary is. The boundary swallows the point and closes into a sphere. Later a new boundary curve opens up and lets out the point.

In the other cases, the same sort of thing happens, except there is one new wrinkle. Let's take the torus for example. The torus starts with a boundary component which swallows the point. Then the boundary component closes to give a closed torus with a point inside. However now the path of the point matters. The point can travel around the torus in loops in either direction some number of times before the boundary component opens up to let the point out again. Different choices of paths would be topologically distinct configurations. For a higher genus surface, the analysis looks much like the torus case, except there is even more choice of path for the point to follow.

I'm not sure if this is the type of description you are looking for, and I'm also not sure how any of this can be used. I hope my description has been helpful in some way.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your thoughtful answer. I am glad to hear that this behavior is essentially the same in higher dimensions (modulo the different g-toric paths which is a very interesting insight). Do you have any recommendations for diving deeper into this, such as how one might go about analyzing the non-orientable cases? As far as application, I am hoping to use these ideas to explore quantum gravity, specifically that different topological states in the world-volume could lead to gravitational anomalies between masses.

Comment: The non-orientable case does not behave as nicely. There are at least two issues. First, when you close up the non-orientable surface, it cannot live inside a 3-dimensional slice. It can only be embedded inside of 4 or more dimensions. Second, a non-orientable surface has no inside or outside. So I don’t think threading can occur.